# Where is the Timer.Elapsed property?

Tags: c#, timer

I have included the `System.Timers` package, but when I type:

```
Timer.Elapsed; //its not working, the property elapsed is just not there.
```

I remember it was there in VB.NET. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the elapsed time since starting the timer?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not a property. [It's an event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx).

So you gotta provide an event handler that will execute every time the timer ticks. Something like this:

```
public void CreateTimer() 
{
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); // fire every 1 second
    timer.Elapsed += HandleTimerElapsed;
}

public void HandleTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // do whatever it is that you need to do on a timer
}
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer because it's shorter hence clearer and to the point.

Comment: I see it's `System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e`  but also, how do you add the timer to the form? I tried `this.Controls.add(timer)` but got an error. as it needs System.Windows.Form.Control

Comment: Could you explain, when to use `+= new ElapsedEventHandler(MyHandler)` and when just `+= MyHandler` ?

Comment: @VassilisGr,  to associate event handler to something you use `+=`; You can also remove the event handler using `-=` syntax.

Comment: So what exactly does line 4 do? It calls a function on the right side of += every second?

Answer (score 6):

Microsofts example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx

Elapsed is an event and therefore requires an eventhandler.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Timer1
{
private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

public static void Main()
{       
    // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
    Console.ReadLine();       
}

// Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
// raised. 
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
}

/* This code example produces output similar to the following:

Press the Enter key to exit the program.
The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2007 8:42:27 PM
The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2007 8:42:29 PM
The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2007 8:42:31 PM
...
 */
```

Comment: I saw this in the microsoft database but i think it has the same funcionality as

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

But i think i solved my problem. Thank you all for answering

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers here are all correct, however with .net 6 / VS2022 now out and about nullability is big deal, and all the above answers will throw compiler warning CS8622.

Your solution will vary by application, but a safe catch all solution is to simply mark the source object as nullable in your callback function's parameters, like such:

```
...
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000); // every 2000ms
    timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsedHandler;
...

public void TimerElapsedHandler(object? source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Your Handling Code Here
}
```

Then if you need to access 'source' for any reason be sure to check if it is null first.

Answer (score 0):

You need an event handler, then after Enabling while assigning event handler and stop in your handler a condition

```
 Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
 Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(PageLoaded);
 Timer.Interval = 3000;
 Timer.Enabled = true;
```

...................

```
 public void PageLoaded(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do what ever here
            if (StopCondition)Timer.Enabled = false;
          
           
        }
```